# Can a BaseX database span multiple folders?

Tags: basex

New to BaseX. Working on a project where 100's or sometimes 1000's of XML files are generated each day. Due to other exogenous factors, the preferred file structure would look like:
 blah/20220714/
 blah/20220715/
 etc…

Is there some way to create this database architecture in BaseX?

In the documentation, a single folder seems to be the only option:
“CREATE DB db /path/to/resources will add initial documents to a database”. It seems there is an ‘ADD’ command available to append files to the database; could this theoretically be run each day to append the new folder that gets created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CREATE DB` to create an empty database or a database with an initial set of documents. If you have a fixed set of resources that you want to import, it’s faster to use this bulk import feature than adding the documents in a second step.

With `ADD`, you can import additional files, directories, remote source, etc. later on, whenever you like.

Comment: Hi Christian, thx for the response.  Just to clarify, there's no parameter or switch available in the CREATE command that automatically includes subdirectories?    Assuming the answer is no, it sounds like I will need to programmatically run the ADD command each day after the new directory is populated. Is this still the preferred way to run commands using Java? : [link](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-examples/src/main/java/org/basex/examples/local/RunCommands.java)

Comment: If you supply an initial directory argument to the CREATE command, all its subdirectories will be parsed as well. It’s a one-time operation, though, so your database won’t get updated if you add new files to the file system. It’s a viable option to call ADD every time after new files have been added.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to point me in the right direction. Danke Shoen!!